# MUI Select custom MenuItem not working properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-forwardref

I have a problem regarding MUI's `MenuItem` when combined with `Select` and rendering it in a separate component.

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-select-custom-menuitem-qq7op)

Basically, I have something like this:

```
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import CustomMenuItem from "./CustomMenuItem";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <Select
      id="user"
      name="User"
      onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        alert(event.target.value as number);
      }}
    >
      {userIds.map((userId) => (
        <CustomMenuItem key={userId} userId={userId} />
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

And this is the custom item:

```
import { MenuItem, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

interface CustomMenuItemProps {
  userId: number;
}

const CustomMenuItem = React.forwardRef<HTMLLIElement, CustomMenuItemProps>(
  (props: CustomMenuItemProps, ref) => {
    const { userId, ...rest } = props;
    return (
      <MenuItem value={userId} {...rest} ref={ref}>
        <Typography>{userId}</Typography>
      </MenuItem>
    );
  }
);
export default CustomMenuItem;
```

At first, I've done this without any refs, but this gave me an error in the console (`Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`), so after googling a while, I found out that I have to pass this ref. I also pass the `...rest` of the props, as I understand that the `MenuItem` needs them.

Expected behavior: when I click on the `MenuItem`, it gets selected in the `Select` component.

Actual behavior: nothing happens.

The thing is, I made the `CustomMenuItem` to make it reusable. But before that, I had a simple function like: `renderItem` which I used both in `Select.renderValue` and in `userIds.map` and it had the same code as `CustomMenuItem` - it returned the same JSX tree. And it worked then, but it doesn't work now, for some reason. So if I would do:

```
    <Select
      id="user"
      name="User"
      onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        alert(event.target.value as number);
      }}
    >
      {userIds.map((userId) => (
        <MenuItem key={userId} value={userId}>
          <Typography>{userId}</Typography>
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
```

it simply works :(

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few implementation details of `Select` that get in the way of trying to customize `MenuItem` in this way.

`Select` [uses the value prop](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L178) of its immediate children. The immediate children of the `Select` in your case are `CustomMenuItem` elements which only have a `userId` prop -- not a `value` prop; so `Select` finds `undefined` as the new value when you click on one of your custom menu items.

You can fix this aspect by duplicating your `userId` prop as a `value` prop:

```
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import CustomMenuItem from "./CustomMenuItem";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);
  console.log("value", value);
  return (
    <Select
      id="user"
      name="User"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setValue(event.target.value as number);
      }}
    >
      {userIds.map((userId) => (
        <CustomMenuItem key={userId} value={userId} userId={userId} />
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MUI Select custom MenuItem]

This then successfully changes the value of the `Select` if you look at the console logs. The new value is **not** successfully displayed due to a separate problem I'll explain later.

You may think "then I can just use the `value` prop instead of the `userId` prop rather than having both", but the `value` prop won't actually reach your custom component. `Select` uses `React.cloneElement` to [change the value prop to undefined](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L304) and instead puts it in `data-value` to avoid a `value` prop being specified in the final html (which wouldn't be a valid attribute for the html element that gets rendered).

In my sandbox above, you'll notice that when you select a value, the new value is not successfully displayed as the selected value. This is because `Select` [uses the children prop of the selected child](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L279) as the display value unless you specify the [renderValue prop](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.1/packages/material-ui/src/Select/SelectInput.js#L240). The `children` prop of the `CustomMenuItem` element is undefined.

You can fix this by either using the `renderValue` prop on the `Select` or by specifying the `userId` yet again as a child:

```
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import CustomMenuItem from "./CustomMenuItem";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);
  console.log("value", value);
  return (
    <Select
      id="user"
      name="User"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setValue(event.target.value as number);
      }}
    >
      {userIds.map((userId) => (
        <CustomMenuItem key={userId} value={userId} userId={userId}>
          {userId}
        </CustomMenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MUI Select custom MenuItem (forked)]

This works, but also removes all of the value the custom menu item component was trying to provide. I think the simplest way to achieve this (while still working well with the Material-UI `Select` design) is to put the reusable code in a function for rendering the menu items rather than making a custom menu item component:

```
import { Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { MenuItem, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";

const renderMenuItem = (value: number) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem key={value} value={value}>
      <Typography>{value}</Typography>
    </MenuItem>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(1);
  console.log("value", value);
  return (
    <Select
      id="user"
      name="User"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<{ value: unknown }>) => {
        setValue(event.target.value as number);
      }}
    >
      {userIds.map(renderMenuItem)}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MUI Select custom MenuItem]

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough explanation! About the last example - this is exactly what I did. I just didn't realize that trying to do this the "component" way would require so much knowledge about MUI internals :) Therefore I am gladly accepting your answer and I'm going back to the helper function approach. Thanks again!

Comment: Funny thing - I've created a function like this, but the problem here is: now TypeScript complains that: `Type '{ renderUserMenuItem: (user: UserData) => Element; }' has no call signatures.`. It has worked before (same function, I copied it from my git history), but when it was defined inside a component. Now it's a free function defined in separate module and it seems that TypeScript treats it as a component? And of course I cannot define it in a component now, since it will be reusable in many places in my code. Sorry to bother again, but do you know how I can get around that?

Comment: @dabljues Please share a sandbox showing the TypeScript issue.

Comment: Okay, it is [that](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-menuitem-issue-8p7lw). And it works. When creating this codesandbox I saw the difference between it and my code: All you guys gonna laugh at me, but the issue was that I was exporting `renderMenuItem` from `renderMenuItem.tsx` like this: `export default { renderMenuItem };` instead of `export default renderMenuItem;`. I know that I should make the default exports without the curly braces. And now looking at it - I thought that it would be an export error or something like this. Try changing the export and the error will appear :)

Comment: Anyway, after changing the export it works, so sorry to bother you again, that was sooo silly of me ;)